# Why is nothing being outputted for this binary search code?

Tags: python, pycharm, binary-search

I have code that supposed to do a binary search on a `list`. The code is executed but nothing is returned. I copied this from a book word for word. I don't know if it's pycharm or if the code is wrong. can you help?

```py
def binarySearch(aList, item):
    start = 0
    end = len(aList) - 1
    index = -1
    found = False
    while start <= end and found:
        mid = (start + end) / 2
        if aList[mid] == item:
            found = True
            index = mid
            print("index at " + str(index))
            return index
        elif aList[mid] < item:
            start = mid + 1
        else:
            end = mid - 1
        return index

nums = [1, 4, 6, 27, 35, 36, 52, 60, 72, 80]

num = 35

binarySearch(nums, num)
```

Comment: Your `found` variable is redundant. Remove it. You assign `False` to it, so that terminates the `while` loop immediately.

Comment: You probably meant `while start <= end and not found`

Comment: btw, when you fix the issue with the `found` variable you will uncover other problems, but they are not related to this question.

Comment: Oh, so if its the case that you really did copy this from a book, then, looking at the answers here, you should definitely consider throwing the book away.

Comment: In case you really need a bisection for an application, have a look at the built in `bisect` module. Otherwise if you want to learn more about the algorithm, I would recommend to implement it yourself from scratch to understand each step in detail instead of debugging some example code. If you run into problems while implementing your version, you can ask your specific questions on your code here.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few mistakes/improvements:

1. Your `found` variable is redundant (mentioned in the comments).
2. You need integer division ('//' instead of  '/').
3. Remove the `return` statement at the end of while loop.
4. No need to have an `index` variable, if not found just return -1 in the end.

So, the fixed version would be:

```
def binarySearch(aList, item):
    start = 0
    end = len(aList) - 1
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if aList[mid] == item:
            return mid
        elif aList[mid] < item:
            start = mid + 1
        else:
            end = mid - 1
    return -1

nums = [1, 4, 6, 27, 35, 36, 52, 60, 72, 80]

num = 35

print(binarySearch(nums, num))
```

Comment: thank you, but now if i change 'num' into a value that's not in the list, -1 in not returned

Comment: @Johnny Hayes, can you show some examples?

Comment: where should i show u?

Comment: Here, please, some input sample that produces incorrect result.

Comment: it just says 'process finished with exit code 0'. nothing is actually in the output box

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your return is inside the while loop, hence why nothing is returned.

After fixing that you'll still return the default index value you sat (-1), and that's because you never enter the loop because the found value is initially "False".

After fixing that you'll still get an error, this time however is easier to figure out, which is that *list indices must be integers or slices, not float*. That's because your **mid** can be a float. To fix that wrap it in an int().

Finally, your code should look something like this

```py
def binarySearch(aList, item):
    start = 0
    end = len(aList) - 1
    index = -1
    found = False
    while start <= end and not found:
        mid = int((start + end) / 2)
        if aList[mid] == item:
            found = True
            index = mid
            print("index at " + str(index))
            return index
        elif aList[mid] < item:
            start = mid + 1
        else:
            end = mid - 1
    return index

nums = [1, 4, 6, 27, 35, 36, 52, 60, 72, 80]

num = 35

print(binarySearch(nums, num))
```

Comment: funnydman's answer is way better. Ignore this